# Run C# script through scheduled task

Tags: c#

I've developed a small script in c# that is querying SQL Server and add computer objects to some Active Directory groups based on certain criteria.   The script is working fine when I run it using the account which has the necessary rights to add/remove objects from Active Directory Group.

When I try to schedule the job, so it runs automatically from server using the "SYSTEM" account it does not work, I get "Access denied"   I've updated the bind account to use the credentials from an account that works but I still have the same issue.

```
> Error Message:
> *2020-01-13 18:32:30,984 [1] ERROR TestAD.clsActiveDirectory - Error occured when trying to add computerobject abcdefg-a10 to group. Error
> message: Access is denied.*
```

The only way to make it work is using the actual account as account to run the scheduled task, however, problem is that our company policy does not allow us to store passwords, so I need to have the account logged-on to run this script.

code snippet

```
                    de.Username = "testing@test.com";
                    de.Password = "xxxxxxxxx";
                    de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
                    de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Sealing;
                    de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Delegation;
                    de.Properties.Count.ToString();
                    ds.SearchRoot = de;
                    ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=" + _myComputerName.ToString() + `"))";`
                    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
                    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
                    ds.SizeLimit = 10;
                    ds.PageSize = 0;
                    ds.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
```

I've tried adding some "AuthenticationTypes" to see if that made difference but still same

any help would be appreciated

Thx.

Comment: I recommend looking into Managed Service Accounts so that you can create an account on the domain.

Comment: Hi Joe, the account I'm using is domain account, and like I've explained already it does work using that account, the issue only occurs if I try to use this in schedule task.   I guess somehow must add something to the binding and/or context but not sure what to add hence the question.

Comment: @DenisGendera you can specify which user will run you task in the scheduler.

Comment: Managed service accounts make it easier to manage the account and do not require a password to be hard coded anywhere.  When you say scheduled task I am not sure if you are referring to SQL Agent or a Windows Task.  I do know that for SQL agent jobs you can set up a proxy with that account so that it does not execute with SYSTEM or NT\Service Account which is the default depending on the login used with the SQL Agent service.

Comment: I'm talking Windows Scheduled task.  I currently have the task configured but using the domain account, it's on test PC and that works, however it's not sustainable long term.   I should be possible to bind to active directory using different account, that's how it's also done for IIS WebSites that need to check Active Directory or other desktop apps  (SCCM) that need to query active directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SQL Server Agents? My company uses them as opposed to Scheduled Tasks. They may be less elegant, but it may be a good alternative to your situation.

- Create a SQL Server Agent that calls the executable with or without parameters.

  - If you cannot call the executable from the hosting OS, you can call an SSIS package on the network to call the executable for you.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I would still like to understand why binding is not working as expected.  Simple test if I run psexec.exe -i -s cmd.exe (System context), and I run my script it also fails.  I'm able to authenticate, I've logged that however when I try to add machine to group I get same error message.  I'm running WireShark trace and see the binding happening it's simple binding against Domain Controller, same binding is happening when I run the script under my account.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and in the end pretty straight forward.
The Active Directory flow is following
- Bind to active directory with my special account and search for the computer object and 
  validate if it needs to be added to Active Directory Group
- if it needs to be added do 2nd bind to the Active Directory group and add computer 
  object.   ==> This piece failed when using scheduled task or run under "SYSTEM" context

Reason for failure:  When I bind 2nd time I did not specify any credentials so it was 
  using default credentials (SYSTEM) if I run the script my account which has enough 
  rights to add computer objects to groups.

I updated code for 2nd bind to include binding credentials and now it's working as 
  expected.

I hope this will be helpful for somebody else who has to troubleshoot similar issues.

old code

```
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(bindString);
        ent.Properties["member"].Add(newMember);
        ent.CommitChanges();
    }
```

New code

```
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(bindString);
        ent.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        ent.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Sealing;
        ent.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Delegation;
        ent.Username = "test123@test.com";
        ent.Password = "test123";
        ent.Properties["member"].Add(newMember);
        ent.CommitChanges();
    }
```